# SQL Выбрать 5 последних записей

Tags: sql

Есть таблица Table и в ней есть колонка CreateDate - время внесения данных. Как выбрать пять последних записей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY CreateDate DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Ваша таблица будет отсортирована по дате, от самой свежей, то есть самой последней внесенной, до самой древней, которую внесли раньше всего (ORDER BY).
А затем будут взяты первые 5 записей (LIMIT 5)

Comment: А как можно сделать это через TOP?

Comment: ```SELECT TOP(5) *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY CreateDate DESC
```